# Postgres PLpgSQL JSON SUM

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to calculate the sum of some JSON values in PLpgSQL (Postgres v9.5.5) but am stuck on the logic.

For this data set:

```
{
  clientOrderId: 'OR836374647',
  status: 'PENDING',
  clientId: '583b52ede4b1a3668ba0dfff',
  sharerId: '583b249417329b5b737ad3ee',
  buyerId: 'abcd12345678',
  buyerEmail: 'test@test.com',
  lineItems: [{
    name: faker.commerce.productName(),
    description: faker.commerce.department(),
    category: 'test',
    sku: faker.random.alphaNumeric(),
    quantity: 3
    price: 40
    status: 'PENDING'
  }, {
    name: faker.commerce.productName(),
    description: faker.commerce.department(),
    category: 'test',
    sku: faker.random.alphaNumeric(),
    quantity: 2,
    price: 30,
    status: 'PENDING'
  }
```

I am trying to get the subtotal of all the lineItems for each row (i.e. quantity * price for each line item, then the sum of these values for the row). So for the above example, the returned value should be 180.

I got this far, but this is returning the totals for all lineItems in the table, not grouped by row.

```
WITH line_items AS (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(line_items) as line_items FROM public.order),
line_item_totals AS (SELECT line_items->>'quantity' AS quantity, line_items->>'price' AS price FROM line_items)

SELECT (quantity::int * price::numeric) AS sub_total FROM line_item_totals;
```

I'm sure the fix is simple but I'm not sure how to do this with JSON fields.

Comment: this is JS Object, not a json?..

Comment: This is the JS object that I'm using to populate the table. The lineItems field is JSONB in the database. All other key/values are just columns in the table.

Comment: sqlfiddle or other playground?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please always include Postgres version you are using. It also looks like your JSON is incorrect. Below is an example of how you can accomplish this with `json` type and **valid** json document.

```
with t(v) as ( VALUES
  ('{
      "clientOrderId": "OR836374647",
      "status": "PENDING",
      "clientId": "583b52ede4b1a3668ba0dfff",
      "sharerId": "583b249417329b5b737ad3ee",
      "buyerId": "abcd12345678",
      "buyerEmail": "test@test.com",
      "lineItems": [{
          "name": "name1",
          "description": "desc1",
          "category": "test",
          "sku": "sku1",
          "quantity": 3,
          "price": 40,
          "status": "PENDING"
        },
        {
          "name": "name2",
          "description": "desc2",
          "category": "test",
          "sku": "sku2",
          "quantity": 2,
          "price": 30,
          "status": "PENDING"
        }]
      }'::JSON)
)
SELECT
  v->>'clientOrderId' cId,
  sum((item->>'price')::INTEGER * (item->>'quantity')::INTEGER) subtotal
FROM
  t,
  json_array_elements(v->'lineItems') item
GROUP BY cId;
```

Result:

```
     cid     | subtotal 
-------------+----------
 OR836374647 |      180
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry - have updated with version number. Currently on v9.5.5.

Comment: Also, I just put the JS object there as some sample data, not actual JSON from the DB.